# The better the question, the worse the votes [halp]?

Tags: discussion

The clearer I phrase my question, the worse are the votes.

Why?

Comment: Can you point to some specific examples...?

Comment: On at least one of your recent questions, someone took quite a bit of time to give you feedback on what wasn't clear about the question.

Comment: @JamesKingsbery and it's still getting close votes. what's your point ?