# I just want to draw attention to a sarcastic and annoying exchange i've had

Tags: discussion

[6-8 people dislike the question within 2 hours: why?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3244/6-8-people-dislike-the-question-within-2-hours-why)

Good question for meta IMO. One answer has 7 upvotes, but it is not specific. A comment tries for something more specific, and it has 5 votes. I will quote from that in full, along with my reply, which was left hanging.

[image]

On another question, I asked for elaboration of why downvote, and it was met with a sarcastic reply.

So anyway, I'm none the wiser.

Comment: "the confusing phrasing, formless composition, and general barrenness of your questions" is this a metaphor? can you be a bit more specific @commando

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere, the confusing phrasing of your questions often render them apparently contextless. That is, while you may strictly speaking do all the things you mention in your comment, your presentation (by my reading) is ineffective at getting your thoughts across. So to a reader, it's difficult to see more than "what is bullshit [viz questions"?" I will supplement this with the observation that commenting "no, you are wrong" on an answer and offering a bare, opaque statement as your only evidence, is neither the most tonally polite way of going about things, nor particularly lurid.

Comment: I apologize if I've come off as hostile; I'm only trying to answer your question. And I'm not sure how it's possible to be specific about one's confusion; the entire point is that I'm not sure what to think when I read e.g. your question on bullshit. Perhaps that's my failing.

Comment: what do you mean "what to think"?

Comment: @commando maybe it is your failing. more likely, we are both failing at something. let us chat about it then be done with it

Comment: @commando i don't see how my statement "it engages with X" is any more opaque than the statement "it doesn't engage with anything", which is the only thing said in that answer with 7 upvotes, though that is fleshed out to three or four lines

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think your original question was a good question for Meta. You seem to be incredibly worried about downvotes you're getting. I get that. But I don't see why we need to have so many Meta questions about that.

> <sub>*Why the downvotes*-kind of questions:
>
>     - [6-8 people dislike the question within 2 hours: why?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3244/2953)
>
>     - [Is over conformity an issue on philosophy stackexchange?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3240/2953)
>
>     - https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3139/2953 (removed)
>
>     - [The better the question, the worse the votes [halp]?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/2953)
>
>   *How to ask*-kind of questions:
>
>     - [Can I ask a question to answer it, instead of pushing a personal philosophy?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3261/2953)
>
>     - [Is this the right attitude to asking questions: teach the reader something?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3251/2953)
>
>     - [Should we not ask questios we're fairly sure don't have an answer in philosophical literature?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3243/2953)
>
>     - https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3226/2953
>
>     - [What really does make a question on topic?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3169/2953)
>
>     - [Does a closing a question for being opinion based even make sense?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3089/2953)</sub>
>
> <sub>Et cetera. I won't even start to try and list all the (deleted) comments about why something was downvoted.</sub>

I would like to say three things about this.

First, it is great that you are concerned about the quality of your posts. But you do not need to be concerned about downvotes. Your overall reputation is increasing on the long run, if that's what you're worried about.

Second, there is almost never a point in discussing why something was downvoted / closevoted, especially if there are just a few negative votes. Al we can do is repeat that negative votes are given as a privilege to users when they know more or less how the site works, and are trusted to use them wisely. Asking why something was downvoted ends up very quickly in speculation.

Third, if you really want to know how to ask good questions, and the second type of questions above is not stimulated by downvotes, you should give much more context. Provide an example of the kind of question you are talking about. Otherwise it remains guessing for us what you're really asking, and the answers won't be as useful as they could have been.

---

I don't think that much more can be said about downvotes than already has been said, so any further questions or comments seem redundant to me.

What is perhaps the best is that you take some time to think about (1) if this site is helpful to you, and (2) if not, if that is because you don't like the format or because you don't understand the format (or something else). If it is because you don't understand the format, try to get to the bottom of the issue and ask a meta question that clearly explains it, preferably with examples. Then we can talk about it. Now I have the feeling we're just answering tangentially related questions without actually helping you.